# Play audio files(.wav) in VB.net w/ volume control

Tags: vb.net, audio, xna, directx, volume

**EDIT: Solved in self-answer below.**

I've looked all over but I can't find anything useful for playing audio files with volume control.
I tried XNA; SLIMDX and "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Audio" but nothing helped.
The options I found which had volume control were too complex and I couldn't figure out how to use, and the method I have currently doesn't let you do anything more than play(background with or without loop, or pause execution until end of play) and stop.

Here's my current code:

```
Dim AD As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Audio
   Sub Play()
        Dim af() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("music.wav")
        AD.Play(af, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
   End Sub
```

This loops "music.wav" in the background, but i cannot pause/seek it or control the volume. Is there any simple way(like the above) to play audio files from a buffer and control the audio volume? I've looked all over but nothing I've found works for my project.

> System: Win7 64-bit
>
> VS version: 2010
>
> Language: VB.net

Oh one more thing, buffering the audio first is something I need for my solution as well(as you can see in my current code)

Does anyone have a solution to this? :)

Comment: I've discovered NAudio to be what I need, but when my app closes i get this error: "WaveOut device was not closed at WaveOut.Finalize()" Anyone know what causes this error? also i checked, there is no "finalize" method in the WaveOut class.

Comment: you need to call WaveOut.Dispose()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer after a bit of searching around so here's the solution I found for my question:

Download [Naudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) and add the references to your project.

Then the following code is how to use it for loading audio from a buffer:

```
Dim Wave1 As New NAudio.Wave.WaveOut 'Wave out device for playing the sound

Dim xa() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\YourPath\YourWave.wav") 'Your Buffer

Sub PlaySound()

        Dim data As New IO.MemoryStream(xa) 'Data stream for the buffer

        Wave1.Init(New NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(New NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(data))))

        Wave1.Volume = 0.1 'Sets the Volume to 10%

        Wave1.Play()

End Sub
```

**WaveFileReader** can be changed to whichever reader you need(i.e. the MP3 one for ".mp3" files) to load your audio file, but the code works as-is for loading ".wav" files.

oh and also, don't forget to

```
WaveOut.Dispose()
```

when you're done to avoid errors.

I hope my research helps somebody :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [Media Player control](http://www.viscomsoft.com/Tutorials/movieplayerpro/1/how_to_create_media_player_application.htm)?

Comment: I tried it just now, but I cannot find a way to load the file from a buffer. Is there a way to load the byte data directly into the MediaPlayer control? via a stream or buffer array

Comment: like this: Dim af() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("music.wav")

Answer (score 0):

hey i hav make a class to handle wave(pcm) file hope this will help u.. its not completed yet but might be helpful.

```
Imports System.IO
```

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Structure WaveHeader
    Public Chunk As Char()
    Public ChunkSize As Int32
    Public Format As Char()
    Public SubChunk1 As Char()
    Public SubChunk1Size As Int32
    Public AudioFormat As Int16
    Public Channels As Int16
    Public SampleRate As Int32
    Public ByteRate As Int32
    Public BlockAlign As Int16
    Public BitsPerSample As Int16
    Public SubChunk2 As Char()
    Public SubChunk2Size As Int32
End Structure

Public Enum State
    None
    Playing
    Paused
    Stopped
    Finished
End Enum

Public Class wav

```
Private watch As New Stopwatch
Private WithEvents timer As New Timer

Private mystate As State = State.None
Private myheader As WaveHeader

Private myurl As String = Nothing
Private mytotaltime As Double = 0

Private Declare Function SetProcessWorkingSetSize Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal process As IntPtr, ByVal minimumWorkingSetSize As Integer, ByVal maximumWorkingSetSize As Integer) As Integer


Event OnPlayStateChange(ByVal e As State)


Public Shared Sub FlushMemory()
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    If (Environment.OSVersion.Platform = PlatformID.Win32NT) Then
        SetProcessWorkingSetSize(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1)
    End If
End Sub

Sub New()
    timer.Interval = 1
    timer.Start()
End Sub

Function readheader(ByVal url As String)
    Dim fh As WaveHeader
    Dim stream As New FileStream(url, FileMode.Open)
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(stream)
    fh.Chunk = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.ChunkSize = br.ReadInt32
    fh.Format = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk1 = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk1Size = br.ReadInt32
    fh.AudioFormat = br.ReadInt16
    fh.Channels = br.ReadInt16
    fh.SampleRate = br.ReadInt32
    fh.ByteRate = br.ReadInt32
    fh.BlockAlign = br.ReadInt16
    fh.BitsPerSample = br.ReadInt16
    For i = 1 To fh.SubChunk1Size - 16
        br.ReadByte()
    Next
    fh.SubChunk2 = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk2Size = br.ReadInt32
    br.Close()
    stream.Close()

    Return Header2String(fh)
End Function

Function Header2String(ByVal fh As WaveHeader)
    Dim t As String = ""
    t &= "Chunk             " & fh.Chunk & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "Chunksize         " & fh.ChunkSize & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "Format            " & fh.Format & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "subChunk1         " & fh.SubChunk1 & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "subchunk1size     " & fh.SubChunk1Size & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "PCM               " & fh.AudioFormat & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "Channels          " & fh.Channels & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "Samplerate        " & fh.SampleRate & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "ByteRate          " & fh.ByteRate & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "Block Align       " & fh.BlockAlign & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "Bits/Sample       " & fh.BitsPerSample & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "subChunk2         " & fh.SubChunk2 & Environment.NewLine
    t &= "subChunk2size     " & fh.SubChunk2Size & Environment.NewLine
    Return t
End Function

Function StopAudio()
    My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
    watch.Stop()
    watch.Reset()
    If PlayState = State.Playing Or PlayState = State.Paused Then
        mystate = State.Stopped
    End If
    Return 0
End Function

Function playAudio(ByVal url As String)
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(url) Then
        Try
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(SongStream(url, 0), AudioPlayMode.Background)
            'My.Computer.Audio.Play(fast(url, 0, CDbl(form1.TextBox4.Text)), AudioPlayMode.Background)

            watch.Restart()
            mystate = State.Playing
            RaiseEvent OnPlayStateChange(State.Playing)
            myurl = url
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Error! Can't Play The File.")
            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        Throw New Exception("File Not Exist.")
    End If
    Return 0
End Function

Function PauseAudio()
    If PlayState = State.Playing Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
        watch.Stop()
        mystate = State.Paused
        RaiseEvent OnPlayStateChange(State.Paused)
    End If
    Return 0
End Function

Function ResumeAudio()
    If PlayState = State.Paused And IsNothing(URL) = False Then
        Try
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(SongStream(URL, time), AudioPlayMode.Background)
            watch.Start()
            mystate = State.Playing
            RaiseEvent OnPlayStateChange(State.Playing)
        Catch : End Try
    End If
    Return 0
End Function


Private Function fast(ByVal url As String, ByVal position As Double, ByVal speed As Single)
    Dim fh As New WaveHeader
    Dim stream As New FileStream(url, FileMode.Open)
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(stream)

    fh.Chunk = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.ChunkSize = br.ReadInt32
    fh.Format = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk1 = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk1Size = br.ReadInt32
    fh.AudioFormat = br.ReadInt16
    fh.Channels = br.ReadInt16
    fh.SampleRate = br.ReadInt32
    fh.ByteRate = br.ReadInt32
    fh.BlockAlign = br.ReadInt16
    fh.BitsPerSample = br.ReadInt16
    fh.SampleRate *= speed
    fh.ByteRate *= speed

    For i = 1 To fh.SubChunk1Size - 16
        br.ReadChar()
    Next

    stream.Position = fh.SubChunk1Size + 20

    fh.SubChunk2 = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk2Size = br.ReadInt32

    If fh.Channels = 6 Then
        fh.Channels = 2
        fh.BlockAlign = fh.Channels * fh.BitsPerSample / 8
        fh.SampleRate = fh.SampleRate * (6 / fh.Channels)
    End If

    position = Math.Round(CInt(position / 1000) * fh.ByteRate)
    If position >= fh.SubChunk2Size Then
        Throw New Exception("Songs isn't that long")
    End If

    mytotaltime = Math.Round(fh.SubChunk2Size / fh.ByteRate)

    fh.SubChunk2Size -= position

    Dim header() As Byte = {Asc("R"), Asc("I"), Asc("F"), Asc("F"), 0, 0, 0, 0, Asc("W"), Asc("A"), Asc("V"), Asc("E"), Asc("f"), Asc("m"), Asc("t"), Asc(" "), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Asc("d"), Asc("a"), Asc("t"), Asc("a"), 0, 0, 0, 0}
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.SubChunk2Size).CopyTo(header, 40)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.BitsPerSample).CopyTo(header, 34)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.BlockAlign).CopyTo(header, 32)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.ByteRate).CopyTo(header, 28)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.SampleRate).CopyTo(header, 24)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.Channels).CopyTo(header, 22)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.AudioFormat).CopyTo(header, 20)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(16).CopyTo(header, 16)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.SubChunk2Size + 36).CopyTo(header, 4)
    myheader = fh
    Dim audio(fh.SubChunk2Size + 44) As Byte
    header.CopyTo(audio, 0)
    stream.Position = position
    br.ReadBytes(fh.SubChunk2Size).CopyTo(audio, 44)

    br.Dispose()
    stream.Dispose()
    br = Nothing
    stream = Nothing

    Return audio
End Function




Private Function SongStream(ByVal url As String, ByVal position As Double)
    Dim fh As New WaveHeader
    Dim stream As New FileStream(url, FileMode.Open)
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(stream)

    fh.Chunk = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.ChunkSize = br.ReadInt32
    fh.Format = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk1 = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk1Size = br.ReadInt32
    fh.AudioFormat = br.ReadInt16
    fh.Channels = br.ReadInt16
    fh.SampleRate = br.ReadInt32
    fh.ByteRate = br.ReadInt32
    fh.BlockAlign = br.ReadInt16
    fh.BitsPerSample = br.ReadInt16

    For i = 1 To fh.SubChunk1Size - 16
        br.ReadChar()
    Next

    stream.Position = fh.SubChunk1Size + 20

    fh.SubChunk2 = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk2Size = br.ReadInt32

    If fh.Channels = 6 Then
        fh.Channels = 2
        fh.BlockAlign = fh.Channels * fh.BitsPerSample / 8
        fh.SampleRate = fh.SampleRate * (6 / fh.Channels)
    End If

    position = Math.Round(CInt(position / 1000) * fh.ByteRate)
    If position >= fh.SubChunk2Size Then
        Throw New Exception("Songs isn't that long")
    End If

    mytotaltime = Math.Round(fh.SubChunk2Size / fh.ByteRate)

    fh.SubChunk2Size -= position

    Dim header() As Byte = {Asc("R"), Asc("I"), Asc("F"), Asc("F"), 0, 0, 0, 0, Asc("W"), Asc("A"), Asc("V"), Asc("E"), Asc("f"), Asc("m"), Asc("t"), Asc(" "), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Asc("d"), Asc("a"), Asc("t"), Asc("a"), 0, 0, 0, 0}
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.SubChunk2Size).CopyTo(header, 40)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.BitsPerSample).CopyTo(header, 34)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.BlockAlign).CopyTo(header, 32)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.ByteRate).CopyTo(header, 28)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.SampleRate).CopyTo(header, 24)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.Channels).CopyTo(header, 22)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.AudioFormat).CopyTo(header, 20)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(16).CopyTo(header, 16)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(fh.SubChunk2Size + 36).CopyTo(header, 4)
    myheader = fh
    Dim audio(fh.SubChunk2Size + 44) As Byte
    header.CopyTo(audio, 0)
    stream.Position = position
    br.ReadBytes(fh.SubChunk2Size).CopyTo(audio, 44)

    br.Dispose()
    stream.Dispose()
    br = Nothing
    stream = Nothing

    Return audio
End Function
```

## Region "Property"

```
<Browsable(False)> ReadOnly Property PlayState
    Get
        Return mystate
    End Get
End Property

<Browsable(False)> ReadOnly Property URL
    Get
        Return myurl
    End Get
End Property

ReadOnly Property TotalTime
    Get
        Return mytotaltime
    End Get
End Property

ReadOnly Property time
    Get
        Return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds
    End Get
End Property

ReadOnly Property timestamp
    Get
        Return watch.Elapsed.ToString
    End Get
End Property
```

## End Region

```
Private Sub timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
    If Not TotalTime = 0 Then
        If TotalTime <= time / 1000 Then
            watch.Stop()
            watch.Reset()
            mystate = State.Finished
            RaiseEvent OnPlayStateChange(State.Finished)
        End If
    End If
    FlushMemory()
End Sub


ReadOnly Property SongHeader As WaveHeader
    Get
        Return myheader
    End Get
End Property
```

End Class

Public Class spactrum

```
Dim h As WaveHeader

Function readheader(ByVal url As String)
    Dim fh As WaveHeader
    Dim stream As New FileStream(url, FileMode.Open)
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(stream)
    fh.Chunk = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.ChunkSize = br.ReadInt32
    fh.Format = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk1 = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk1Size = br.ReadInt32
    fh.AudioFormat = br.ReadInt16
    fh.Channels = br.ReadInt16
    fh.SampleRate = br.ReadInt32
    fh.ByteRate = br.ReadInt32
    fh.BlockAlign = br.ReadInt16
    fh.BitsPerSample = br.ReadInt16
    For i = 1 To fh.SubChunk1Size - 16
        br.ReadByte()
    Next
    fh.SubChunk2 = br.ReadChars(4)
    fh.SubChunk2Size = br.ReadInt32
    h = fh
    Return br.ReadBytes(fh.SubChunk2Size)
End Function


Function showit()
    Dim b As New Bitmap(500, 200)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b)
    Dim d() As Byte = readheader("songs\s.wav")
    'Dim t As Integer = d.Count
    For i = 0 To d.Count - 1
        Dim x = CInt((i / d.Count) * 500)
        Dim y = CInt(d(i).ToString) - 200
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, 0, x, y)
    Next

    'g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 500, 300)
    Return b.Clone
End Function
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

As there seems to be little documentation on using naudio in VB.NET, rather than the C# examples found everywhere, and further to @user1666788's comments, this is a simple way of making it play an MP3 file for VB.NET, rather than a WAV.

```
Public Shared Wave1 As New NAudio.Wave.WaveOut 'Wave out device for playing the sound

Public Sub btn_PlayPause_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_PlayPause.Click

        Dim file As String = "C:\test.mp3"
        Dim data As New NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(file)
        Wave1.Init(data)
        Wave1.Play()
End Sub
```